# What was Dumbledore's fallback plan in case Harry fails?

Tags: harry-potter

Is there any canon support whether Dumbledore had a fallback plan in case that Harry fails?

As a start - Harry is hardly the best choice for the one to hunt down and kill Voldemort. There are more experienced people at hand who can do it and have much better chances to succeed.

Yes - Harry had a unique advantage of the double protection coming from his mother's blood that was later transferred to Voldemort. Yes - Harry is "the chosen one" according to the prophecy although prophecies depend a lot on what people do and are not guaranteed to come true just because they exist.

There are a lot of places where Harry could've been just killed together with Hermione and Ron and the whole knowledge about the hocruxes would've been lost.

Comment: "prophecies depend a lot on what people do and are not guaranteed to come true just because they exist." Tell that to Oedipus.

Comment: "prophecies... are not guaranteed to come true just because they exist." Well, they kinda are, by definition. Otherwise they aren't real prophecies.

Comment: I doubt there's canon that directly supports alternative plans. But, you get a pretty clear picture after Dumbledore's death that certain plans and knowledge were *not* given to anyone but Harry, and team Harry had very little to go on. For instance: It took them forever to figure out how to destroy a Horcrux, and we never see anyone but RAB aware of the Horcruxes. If someone else was in the loop, then they should have been assisting at some point.

Comment: @phantom42 Dear Oedipus: It really depends on what people do. If you hadn't killed that man who turned out to be your father, and married that woman who turned out to be your mother, then the Oracle would have been wrong!

Comment: Dumbledore probably planned to take care of all of the horrocrux's himself, unfortunately, he messed up with the ring so Harry himself, was a contingency plan.

Comment: I guess I need to revisit the books. I could have sworn that there is a quote about the Department of Mysteries along the lines of "all prophecies are held here whether they come true or not".

Comment: In case Harry failed, he was going to call the Avengers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dumbledore didn't have a backup plan.

> ‘The last words Albus Dumbledore spoke to the pair of us?’
>   ‘“Harry is the best hope we have. Trust him,”’ said Lupin calmly.
>   <sub>*Deathly Hallows* - page 65 - Bloomsbury - chapter five, *Fallen Warrior*</sub>

Dumbledore had complete faith in Harry.

There is no mention of a backup plan in canon, nor has J.K. Rowling ever addressed the possibility in any of her interviews.

Comment: I don't know that it was a backup plan, but he did point Harry towards confiding in his friends.  Three is a more survivable group than one, and Harry kept with this concept by giving Neville information before he left for the forest.

Comment: So Dumbledore's plan was [The Power of Friendship](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThePowerOfFriendship), and his ace-in-the-hole was [The Power of Love](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThePowerOfLove).

Comment: Could Neville have done it if Harry died?

Comment: @CanadianGirlScout I believe this question(Or some **VERY** similar) has been asked in numerous forms on this site, go check them out :)

Comment: @LepelLeLama - the question is not about "what would have happened if Voldemort went for Neville instead of Harry".

Comment: @vap78 I know, but there are many notions of 'would Neville have been able to do what Harry had done' and in general those answers suggest yes. But they are not EXACTLY about that, which is why i stated "very similar" :), and since it didn't happen we won't ever know for sure.

Comment: @KSmarts - Are you implying that Dumbledore's magic runs on TVTropes?

Comment: @Slytherincess - I'm highly troubled that you'd put your trust into a source as habitually lying and untrustworthy as Albus Dumbledore.

Comment: @DVK Yes. Years ago, Dumbledore introduced the Astral Plane to TVTropes. That is why it took Voldemort so long to get around to getting a new body.

Comment: @KSmarts This suggests summoning the combined might of Princess Twilight Sparkle and Huey Lewis and the News.